# Contact form php inside html

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to include a contact form with validation inside my html file with php. I would like the answer to be in the same page without redirecting to another one. I have added the php snippet before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` but on the top of my page it displays the error message [image]

Also inside the contact forms i am getting tags `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>`

and such. I am new to php so i would need your help

Here's the code:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'example@domain.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name'])
        {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message'])
        {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5)
        {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }
       // If there are no errors, send the email
       if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman)
       {
          if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from))
          {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
          }
          else
          {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
          }
       }
    }
?>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="#">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <?php echo $result; ?>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

in the action="#" i included the # so that it stays on the same page

forgot to mention that when i complete the form it says cannot post

Comment: forgot to mention that when i complete the form it says cannot post

Comment: Just a side note, is a typo that the closing `</div>` of `<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">`isn't in your code or?

Comment: It looks like your PHP code is not being executed. Can you try something simple like <?php echo 'Hello Worls'; ?> and see if that does anything. Does the file have a .php extension?

Comment: no the file is in html!

Comment: php code requires to have the .php extension before it will run. Also make sure PHP is enabled on your webserver

Comment: i am currently developing in my local pc!

Comment: Are you using XAMP or another tool / client /server as website?

Comment: do i have to create a new php file? and replace action with the created php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at "View source" you will likely see the < ?php-tags, meaning PHP is not executed.

Check the extension of your file (it has to be X.php where x is the name you want) and make sure your webserver supports PHP.

If you are developing locally. Make sure you have PHP installed.

Take a look at http://www.php.net to download and install PHP for your operating system. If you are using windows, I would advise installing WAMP. You can find it [here](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: Okay because i am a little bit confsed now. For this to work, do i need to create a separate php file and replace it with action="something.php" in my html? or is it okay to put the snippet before my actual html?

Comment: you can put the entire html code in a .php file. it will run perfectly fine. (If PHP is installed ofc.)

Comment: You can leave the file contents just change its extension, and access through a webserver ( install wamp)

Comment: now the only problem is that i am getting a notice like this: b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: message in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\site\contact-us.php</b>

Comment: It means the post fields are not defined. (probably not submitted yet?)

try using  $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'Unknown' ;
        $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : 'unknown';
        $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : 'not defined';

Comment: Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as the solution :-)